# Debian conky installation

Tags: linux, bash, debian, conky

I messed up in conky installation. Conky is installed on computer but terminal says: **conky is already the newest version (1.10.6-1).** but when i write conky in terminal bash tells me: **bash: conky: command not found**. I've deleted some conky files too (i think that's reason why it's not working). So is there any possible way to fix this or should i reinstall my debian

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for reply I will post my problem there

Answer (score 0):

You can check the integrity of a package using [debsums](https://packages.debian.org/sid/debsums)

```
debsums conky
```

If there are corrupted or missing files, you can reinstall the package :

```
aptitude reinstall conky
```

or

```
apt-get install --reinstall conky
```